# Script to find files in subdirectories

Tags: windows, bash, search, cygwin

I need a script that will find and get me all files in all subdirectories (and leave them in the folder structure as they are now). I know how to find and print that files:

```
find . -name "something.extension"
```

The point is, in those directories are lots files that was used before, but I don't want to get those, so the script should only find me files that matches some kind of path pattern which is:

```
xxx/trunk/xxx/src/main/resources
```

xxx is different everytime, and after resources there are still some folders that directories are different based on xxx.

Every top xxx folder contains folder named 'tags' (the same level as trunk) that stores previous releases of module (and every release has files that name I am looking for, but I don't want outdated files).

So I want to find all that files in subdirectories of that path pattern that I specified and copy to new location but leave folder structure as it is right now.

I am using Windows and cygwin.

**Update**

I combined answer commands that 'that other guy' posted below, and it works. Just to be clear I have something like this:

```
find */trunk/*/src/main/resources -name "something.extension" -exec mkdir -p /absolute/target/path/{} \; -exec cp {} /absolute/target/path/{} \;
```

Thanks.

Comment: Is eliminating all matches that occur under a `tags` directory enough to satisfy this request? Is only matching under paths that include `trunk` enough?

Comment: I think skipping everything that is under 'xxx/tags' folder should be ok. 'xxx' is module name, and there are lots of modules. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of searching under the entire current directory (`.`), just search under the directories you care about:

```
find */trunk/*/src/main/resources -name "something.extension"
```

Comment: Just for the record, if the expansion of those wildcards matches too many directories (and the path is long enough) this might run into maximum command line length limits.

Comment: Ok, but how to copy all founded results into new directory keeping old folders structure?

Comment: @damian_pol `-exec mkdir -p /target/path/{} \; -exec cp {} /target/path/{} \;`